# Factory of objects with different constructors

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, ninject, abstraction

There is an interface IRule with one method Validate() and several derived classes from it which implement this method. Classes are with different ctors (types and number of arguments). In addition, there is a core interface named IPaymentProcessor which has to validate all existing Rules.
My current task is to implement high-level abstraction like factory or container which ideally creates all rules with different constructors and then returns them as IEnumerable to iterate and apply each rule for card validation.

*Is it possible to complete the task using Ninject or any other reflection-based library in .NET? (AutoFixture, Moq, etc.)*

Here is a current solution, which I wanted to improve.

```
public interface IRule
 {
        bool Validate();
 }

  class Rule1 : IRule
  {
      public Rule1(string name) { ... }
      bool Validate() { ... }
  }

  class Rule2 : IRule
  {
      public Rule1(int month, int year) { ... }
      bool Validate() { ... }
  }

  interface IPaymentProcessor
  {
    bool MakePayment(CreditCard card);
  }

  class MyPaymentProcess : IPaymentProcessor
  {
    public bool MakePayment(CreditCard card)
     {
        // Here is pitfall. If we need to add/remove another rule or one of
        // ctors changed, then we have to edit this place, which isn't flexible
        var rules = new List<IBusinessRule>() { new Rule1(card.Name), new Rule2(card.Month, card.Year) };  
        foreach(var r in rules) if(!r.Validate()) { return false; }
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe what you need is interface with bool Validate(CreditCard card) rule, not just Validate().

Comment: Yes, it should be much convenient, but I've got this code as is from other people as a task and can't modify it.

Comment: Anyway passing name and other data into constructor won't work good, you need to pass whole CreditCard to rule in one form or another.

Comment: Yes - for production code, No - for test task ;)

Answer (score 0):

It ultimately seems you want to validate a credit card, so I don't really understand why you are creating different rules to validate specific properties of the credit card and not implement a general rule that validates the card as a whole.

If, for reasons I am unaware of, you need to create rules
that validate independently the name, expiring date, number, etc. you still have a very simple way of doing so; simply pass de card in the constructor and let each rule validate the information it's supposed to;

```
public NameRule(CreditCard card) { ... }
public bool Validate() => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(card.Name);
```

A cleaner solution and one you'd need to use if you didn't know the card you'd be validating when creating the rules, is passing in the constructor a `Predicate<CreditCard>`. In this case you wouldn't even need more than one rule type:

```
var nameRule = new Rule<CreditCard>(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Name));
var dateRule = new Rule<CreditCard>(c => c.Date > DateTime.
```

Being the implementation of `Rule`:

```
public class Rule<T>
{
    private readonly Predicate<T> myPredicate;
    public Rule(Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        myPredicate = predicate;
    }

    public bool Validate(CreditCard card) => myPredicate(card);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for tips. It is an academical task to show knowledge in DI, low class dependency, SOLID principles etc.

Comment: @DenisK. I've updated the answer with what I'd consider the best  solution; you don't really need different rule types, specialized instances are enough.

Comment: I've got the idea, there is no way to edit existing classes which is Rule1, Rule2. They should stay as is. Although, a part of your solution I've add to my new separated class RulesFactory. Where existing IRule instance creators (Func<CreditCard, IRule> ) registering and then factory returns all registered creatars on demand. The solution will post below a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

The source of your trouble here is the fact that you try to construct application components (your business rule implementations) with runtime data (properties from a `CreditCard` instance that is only know at runtime), while [injecting application components with runtime data is an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Instead, your components should be stateless, and by passing runtime data through the public API of the `IRule` abstraction, you prevent having to create such component inside a factory (since [factories are a code smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100)), and you prevent these maintenance problems as you described in your questions.

@InBetween made a very good comment about making the `IRule` abstraction generic, because this allows creating a type-safe business rule implementation that exactly defines what it verifies:

```
public interface IBusinessRule<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<string> Validate(TEntity entity);
}
```

Also note that I changed `Validate` so that it doesn't return a boolean, but rather a collection of (zero or more) validation errors. This allows communicating more clearly why the system stopped processing your request.

Implementations might look as follows:

class CreditCardNameNotEmpty : IBusinessRule
  {
      public IEnumerable Validate(CreditCard entity) {
          if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entity.Name)
              yield return "Credit card name should not be empty.";
      }
  }

By moving the runtime data out of the constructor, it now allows us more easily to construct application components that contain dependencies of their own. For instance:

class CreditCardDateIsValid : IBusinessRule
  {
      private readonly ILogger logger;
      public CreditCardDateIsValid(ILogger logger) {
          this.logger;
      }

```
  public IEnumerable<string> Validate(CreditCard entity) {
      // etc
  }
```

}

Although we could inject an `IEnumerable<IBusinessRule<T>>` into components that need business rule validation, this wouldn't be good to do, because this would force the consumer to iterate the returned collection, which would cause a lot of code duplication. So instead, we want to hide the `IBusinessRule<T>` abstraction from the consumer and present them with an abstraction that is more focussed to their needs. For instance:

```
public interface IValidator<T>
{
    // Throws a ValidationException in case of a validation error.
    void Validate(T instance);
}
```

We can easily implement this as follows:

```
public class Validator<T> : IValidator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IBusinessRule<T>> rules;

    public Validator(IEnumerable<IBusinessRule<T>> rules) {
        if (rules == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rules));
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    public void Validate(T instance) {
        if (instance == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(instance));

        var errorMessages = rules.Select(rule => rule.Validate(instance)).ToArray();

        if (errorMessages.Any()) throw new ValidationException(errorMessages);
    }
}
```

This allows us to simplify the payment processor to the following:

```
class MyPaymentProcess : IPaymentProcessor
{
    private readonly IValidator<CreditCard> creditCardValidator;

    public MyPaymentProcess(IValidator<CreditCard> creditCardValidator) {
        this.creditCardValidator = creditCardValidator;
    }

    public void MakePayment(CreditCard card)
    {
        this.creditCardValidator.Validate(card);

        // continue the payment
    }
}
```

Note that the `MakePayment` method now doesn't return a `bool` anymore. This is because if an operation can't do what it promises to do (in this case making the payment) it should throw an exception. By returning a boolean, you are returning an error code, which is a practice we left behind ages ago.